# What software was used to write real-world haskell?

Tags: layout, web, formatting, haskell

Title pretty much sums it up; I'm looking to start a book on programming and I love that approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.realworldhaskell.org/blog/2008/11/25/real-world-haskell-is-shipping/

From this blog post (read the comments), it seems they used DocBook.